# returning 2 values from a func

Tags: python, tkinter

Anyone has an idea why the following code generates error??

I call a func to get mouse coordinates:

```
def button_click(event):
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    print('{}, {}'.format(x, y))
    return x, y
```

and then I want to assign the results to new variables in main:

```
x_cord, y_cord = app_root.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', button_click)
```

by doing this I get the following error:

```
"x_cord, y_cord = app_root.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', button_click)
ValueError: too many values to unpack"
```

Anyone has an idea why this is happening? Thank you everybody!

Comment: You have no indentation?

Comment: What does `app_root.bind` return?

Comment: Could you provide full stacktrace?

Comment: app_root is my main thing.  I start the program with: def main():
    app_root = Tk()

Comment: The question was: what does `app_root.bind` return?

Comment: `bind` does not return a coordinate pair.

Comment: i am not sure..... from the Tkinter documentatin: widget.bind(event, handler)
If an event matching the event description occurs in the widget, the given handler is called with an object describing the event.

Comment: It's bad practice, but use global variables.

Comment: how should i write my code in order to return x,y values?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is bad practice but you can declare the scope of variables as `global` to access them elsewhere:

```
def button_click(event):

    global x, y

    x = event.x
    y = event.y
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using `Tkinter`, `bind()` would only bind an event to your `button_click` callback and return an event identifier. Quote from the `bind()` docstring:

> `Bind` will return an identifier to allow deletion of the bound function
>   with unbind without memory leak.

You cannot expect `bind()` to return what your `button_click()` event handler returns.

Comment: In other words, `bind` was not designed to return a coordinate tuple.